# PYTHON how to decompress a string with int

Tags: python

decompress('ab3d') -> abbbd

decompress('i4j3i') ->iiiijjji

That's what I 'd like my function to return. However i can not figure out what's wrong with my code. I am really confused. Here's what I have for now:

```
def decompress(m):
    x = 0
    result = ''

    while len(m) - x > 1:
        a = m[x + 1]
        if type(a) != int:
            result += m[x]
        elif type(a) == int:
            result += m[x] * m[x + 1]
        x = x + 1

    if m[len(m) - 1] == str:
        result += m[len(m) - 1]

    print result
```

my result is ab3 & i4j3

Comment: What does it output? Also I'd double check your indenting.

Comment: Some feedback on your code. First, `type(a)==str` and `type(a)==int` do nothing in your code. Second, `a` must be a string, unless you `int(a)`. Third, it is meaningless to use two while loops, put them into one. Forth, use `your_variable += ...` instead of `your_variable = your_variable + ...`

Comment: Initially your `m` is a string. So all the characters in it are still type string. So there is no point of checking `type(a)!=int` as `a` is a string already (difference between `4` and `"4"`). And if you need to check the `type` if a object I suggest to use `isinstance(<object>, <type>)`.

Comment: What would you want for `"a23b"`? Should it give `"aa3b"`, `"a222b"`, or `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"`?

Comment: I tried to use "isinstance(int(a),int) == Ture" it returns an syntax error, why is that?

Comment: a23b should return aaaaaaaaa...b